# Finding intersection of two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having trouble finding what's wrong with my code - at first I thought I was finished, but then I found some issues. I am creating a function called bagIntersection that takes two bag objects and finds common items in both, and then places them into a new bag:

For example, if bag has items {"b", "b", "c"} and bag2 has items {"b", b", "d", "e"}, the function call:

```
ArrayBag<std::string> resultBag = bag.bagIntersection(bag2);
```

should only return string "b" in the resultBag. My function bagIntersection is returning {"b","b"} into the resultBag. So somehow I'm getting multiples of "b".

(code removed) The code was correct.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: is this some kind of exercise? I think you could solve it much easier by using eg `std::set`

Comment: I don't see what's wrong. The intersection of `{"b", "b", "c"}` and `{"b", b", "d", "e"}` *is* `{"b","b"}`.

Comment: `resultBag.getFrequencyOf(resultBag.items[i])` should probably be `resultBag.getFrequencyOf(items[i])`.

Comment: @Nelxiost I must have misunderstood the directions, you're right. Sorry.

Comment: @Jarod42 if I pass items[i] as an argument, does it grab the items array from resultBag? Just trying to understand a little better. Thanks!

Comment: `items[i]` is the member of the object whose method is beeing called. If you want items from the parameter you have to write `aBag.items[i]`, or `resultBag.itmes[i]` for the items of the result

Comment: @tobi303 Thank you for clarifying

Comment: Inside a method, writing `items` (or any other member) is the same as `this->items`. For some reason this is widely disliked, but I think it can improve readability sometimes

Comment: Sort both arrays. Then write a merge loop to get the intersection. Don't output anything twice.

Comment: @Pythonguy maybe you could just remove duplicates in the solution found by your existing code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove duplicate you can do like this with a vector container for example :

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
```

and you will have only one "b".

Comment: You could expand on the OPs original problem: finding a set intersection e.g. using `std::set_intersection`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this function and it's a powerful function.